# How to make FFmpeg wait for input

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I have a program which saves game play in a file. I want to run FFmpeg and give the file as input for live streaming. Below is how I use FFmpeg to stream the video file.

```
%ffmpeg% -re -i %fileloc%%file%.mpg -deinterlace -vcodec h264_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv420p -s hd720 -threads 4  -preset fast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2000k -ar 44100 -b:a 4000000 -bufsize 2049k -f flv rtmp://live-dfw.twitch.tv/app/live_key 2> %fileloc%%file%_Info.tx
```

However I have some problems when game fps drops below 30 fps. I suppose FFmpeg is not waiting for input file to be written and reaches the end. Is that correct or something else is happening? Is there a parameter that tells FFmpeg to wait instead of closing?